# Numbersでcsvをインポートすると電話番号の先頭のゼロが削除される

Tags: macos

表題の通りなのですが、Appleのofficeアプリケーションの「Numbers」を利用して
CSVデータをインポートすると、電話番号データの先頭のゼロが削除されてしまいます。

```
09012341234 → 9012341234
```

これを回避するために、いろいろと調べてみたのですが
英文での説明しか出てこなくて、なんとか和訳して読み取ってみると
数字の先頭に`'`をつけると良いというような記述があったりしたので
大量のデータの該当箇所に`'`を付けてみたのですが、
先頭のゼロは削除されることはなくなったものの
今度は先頭に`'`が付いてしまいます（当たり前か）

どうすればNumbersでcsvを開くときに、すべてのデータを文字列として読み込むことができるのでしょうか？